# Unable to debug assembly program using GDB on ARMv7

Tags: linux, gdb, armv7

I am having trouble debugging an ARMv7 assembly program using GDB.

```
$ uname -a
Linux cptr280 5.15.0-1017-raspi #19-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri Oct 14 08:24:06 UTC 2022 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I have an assembly program that I assemble and link as follows:

```
as -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfpv2 -g $file.s -o $file.o
ld $file.o -o $file -lc -lm \
  --dynamic-linker=/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 \
  --rpath=/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

The program runs fine on its own but when I start it in GDB and place a breakpoint in `_start`, it tells me that it will stop in my program, but instead it stops in

```
Breakpoint 1, 0xb6fe0a94 in _start () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
```

When I continue from that point I get the following:

```
Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
__GI__dl_debug_state () at dl-debug.c:117
```

Can you explain to me what is happening? Is this because I'm using dynamic linking? If so, how would I go about doing static linking for the standard C library and the math library?

Comment: This seems similar to https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/766 but that involved changes to the RaspberryPI OS, and I'm running Ubuntu.

Comment: My current theory is that some of the code is in THUMB mode and GDB is not properly recognizing the change in mode.

Comment: Finally I had to abandon Ubuntu and switch to Raspberry Pi OS and things now work.